# Paypal API SDK Chained Payments

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/ does this SDK support adaptive/chained payments in .Net and if so can you provide an example of how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Net Adaptive payment SDK: https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-dotnet . in the package, there is a samples folder, you can deploy the code to have a try.

Comment: From the documentation:
"This Classic SDK is not actively supported and will be deprecated in the future.".